# origin has been blocked by CORS policy Spring boot and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, controller, cors-anywhere

## Spring Boot with React

#### Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:

**This is a contoller which return all district objects**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/ from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
package com.ministry.demo.controller;

import com.ministry.demo.model.District;
import com.ministry.demo.repository.DistrictRepository;
import com.ministry.demo.service.DistrictService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "district")
public class DistrictController {
    @Autowired
    DistrictService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "getAll")
    List<District> getAllDistrict(){
        return service.getAllDistricts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**I found an Answer**

```
package com.ministry.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "district")
public class DistrictController {
    @Autowired
    DistrictService service;

    @GetMapping(path = "getAll")
    List<District> getAllDistrict(){
        return service.getAllDistricts();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

**MyConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Found an alternative answer that works for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

If your backend and your app are not running on the same address your browser does normally not allow you to call your backend.
This is intended to be a security feature.

To allow your browser to call your api add the Access-Control-**** headers to your backend response (when answering from Spring).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Most basic header that allows all origins:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Here is a tutorial for adding those headers in Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: after I use the @CrossOrigin annotation the error has gone. thank you

Answer (score -1):

The problem was on my springboot backend since I did not add some control headers.
I've added some access control headers in my springboot api to fix the error.

Error: net::ERR_FAILED 200
FrontEnd: reactjs
Backend: Springboot API[JWT]

**reactjs:**

```
      const LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/login";
      const params = new URLSearchParams()
      params.append('email', email)
      params.append('password',password)
    
      const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL, params);
```

**springboot/java:**

```
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication){
       ...
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
       response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range");
       ...
    }
```