# SpringBoot blocked by CORS policy

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have encounter below error when I use a front end source code to call my backend java server.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8513/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:9513' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I'm using springboot(2.2.4.RELEASE) + OAuth2(2.2.1.RELEASE)+Jwt(1.0.9.RELEASE). Paste my pom.xml here

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have add the configuration to allow CORS police, but it seem that it not work at all.
My security configuration are here

JWTOAuth2Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class JWTOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final int accessTokenValiditySeconds = 5 * 60 * 1;
    private static final int refreshTokenValiditySeconds = 60 * 60 * 1;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private TokenEnhancer jwtTokenEnhancer;


    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter;


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(jwtTokenEnhancer, jwtAccessTokenConverter));

        endpoints
        .tokenStore(tokenStore)
        .accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter)
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

      clients.inMemory()
              .withClient("organization")
              .secret(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder().encode("organization666"))
              .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
              .scopes("webclient", "mobileclient")
              .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
              .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(refreshTokenValiditySeconds);
  }
}
```

ResourceServerConfiguration.java
config allow CORS at class HttpSecurity in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, but not work.

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/moikiitos/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and().cors()
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

config allow CORS at class HttpSecurity in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, not work also.
WebSecurityConfigurer.java

```
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Value("${security.enable-csrf}")
    private boolean csrfEnabled;


    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception{
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        if(!csrfEnabled) {
            http.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
}
```

set csrf to flase in 
application.properties

```
security.enable-csrf=false
```

even I also use below java code configuraton for WebMvcConfiguer, but it not work also.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9513")
        .allowedMethods("*")
        .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

What's more, I also use this @CrossOrigin on my controller.
Someone can help me in it. Appreciate.
I have read some articles such as [origin has been blocked by CORS policy Spring boot and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775325/origin-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-spring-boot-and-react)
but not help me.

Comment: at this moment, I used nginx to combine my front application in port 9513 and spring boot app in port 8513 under some port. But I need to allow csrf. If you need my full code base, you can find here https://github.com/ChenLin12138/Moikiitos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. Cos I used Oauth + JWT in spring security. Spring security used filter to setup cors, but there are few filter in spring security. **(@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE))** So setup a sequence for my filter is important. attached source code for your reference.

Cors config

```java
@Configuration
public class GlobalCorsConfiguration {

     @Bean
        public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
            CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
            corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
            corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
            return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
        }
}
```

Auth config

```java
//This @Order is very important to setup the sequence of filter in spring security.
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception{
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/**")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable().formLogin()
        .and()
        .cors();
    }
}
```

Resource config

```java
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/moikiitos/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/v1/moikiitos/user/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/v1/moikiitos/**").authenticated();       
    }
}
```