# Java Spring-Boot Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I want to connect react with spring boot application but when I open security settings

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sporcu/all' from origin 'http://localhost:3000/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access- Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

i get the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [origin has been blocked by CORS policy Spring boot and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775325/origin-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-spring-boot-and-react)

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Anotate your spring boot controller class with this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
```

**Set the localhost port number as react listens**

Answer (score 0):

Use @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") annotation Above your controller class

Comment: This "works" in that it allows `http://localhost:3000` to make cross-origin requests to the server, but it does allow cross-origin requests from *any* client, which may well create security issues. You should only do this in a production service if you really know what you are doing.

Comment: yes, you right. this allow all client. this will create security problem