# front end blocked by cors policy event port is whitelisted

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to call an api from backend in spring boot v3.1 from my frontend which is running in 4200 however it says
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/writer/create' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

why 4200 still blocked even if i have this code on my backend  @Configuration

---

@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

```
private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers("api/v1/auth/**","reader/**")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/writer/**").hasAnyAuthority("WRITER")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement(session ->         session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return  http.build();
}


@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
            "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new   UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

    return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
}

}
```

to success fully call my backend from my front end

Answer (score 0):

For CORS with front-end, check out this Spring documentation documentation. The main take-away is the @CrossOrigin annotation.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Another similar question ended up solving this problem via the use of the Cross Origin annotation on the controller class.

[origin has been blocked by CORS policy Spring boot and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775325/origin-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-spring-boot-and-react?rq=2)